# How to extract only date from moment object

Tags: javascript

I am using moment object for date.
and for that i wrote

```
dateOnly = moment(date.format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
var ndate = dateOnly.toDate();
```

I want to display only date on front end but it is showing me in this format that I don't want

> Mon Feb 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use moment's format function to display date in the format you want to

```
moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'); // "02/22/2016"
```

You can go through all the available formats here

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 2):

```
var dateOnly = moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY'); // for formatted dates.
yesterday= moment(date).subtract(1,'days') // for previous day 
//you can replace days with months and years.
tomorrow= moment(date).add(1,'days') // for upcoming day 
//you can replace days with months and years. 
var date1= moment(yesterday)
var date2= moment(tomorrow)
differencebetweenmoments =moment(date1).diff(moment(date2),'days');
```